# How to identify a browser-window as a popup in Firefox-Extension?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, xul

We are a bit in trouble.

We show some informations for specific sites in our own firefox extension (for several reasons we use a xul box-Element for that presentation).
We don't wan't the box to show in browser popups.

But: How do we identify a browser-window as a popup in our extension code (javascript)?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may check:

1. if the window does have an opener => `if(window.opener)`
    *to determine if it was opend using javascript*
2. if the window does have an opener, check if it is  the top-window =>`if(self==top)`
    *to determine that the window is not a frame*

When both conditions are true, you may assume that the window is a popup.

Comment: Thanks. But: window.opener is always NULL. Why?

Comment: Actually either the site doing the opening or the site being opened can set window.opener to null.  So it's not a reliable method of detecting windows opened via javascript.  Furthermore, window.opener is non-null for windows opened by targeted links, even if no javascript was involved...